# Adobe Campaign - Query multiple schemas

Tags: javascript, adobe, workflow, campaign-monitor

In Adobe campaign I have several (400+) schemas so I need to query all of them to see if they have recent data so that I will know what schemas need to monitor. To do this I will use the creation date on every schema. The problem is that I don't want to do it manually (go 1 by 1), is there a way to automate this and get all the schemas let's say using java script and then use a query with the creation date and pass a specific date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is possible, you may avoid it and try to consider as @theopendle mention, a database level query.

Nevertheless, just use the Source schema (xtk:srcSchema) and you will have all the schemas listed. Then you can use that retrieved schema in your next "monitoring" process.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using Adobe Campaign Classic (on premise) not Standard (cloud versions):

As far as I know, there is no way to easily do this from within Campaign. However, all the schemas you can query using the Generic Query Editor or in a worflow correspond to tables in the Oracle database on which AC is based. If you connect to this database you can run regular Oracle SQL queries which gives you much more control.